# JNI memory management

Tags: java, android, c++, c, java-native-interface

***Question 1:*** In the function below I want to **call** `ReleaseStringUTFChars` **method before returning value**. How I can do that as in this case may application crashes.

```
String JNIXMLDOMDocument::GetXML() const
{
    String strXML;

    jmethodID method = m_JavaEnv->GetMethodID(m_XMLDomDocClass, "GetXML", "(Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;)Ljava/lang/String;");
    if(method == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    jstring jstrXML = (jstring)m_JavaEnv->CallObjectMethod(m_XMLDomDocClassObject, method, m_XMLDomDocument);
    if (jstrXML == NULL) {
    return strXML;
    }

    strXML = m_JavaEnv->GetStringUTFChars(jstrXML, 0);

    /* Question 1:  **/
    m_JavaEnv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstrXML, strXML.c_str());

    return strXML;

} /* String GetXML() const **/
```

---

***Question 2:*** Is it correct to attach thread in the constructor and use it in all functions, and detach in the destructor, if my application use multithreading ?

```
JNIXMLDOMDocument::JNIXMLDOMDocument()
{
    /* Check If the current thread is attached to the virtual machine. **/
    int needToDetach;
    /* Question 2:  **/
    m_JavaEnv = AttachCurrentThread(&needToDetach);
    if (m_JavaEnv != NULL)
    {
        /* Try to find JAVA 'XMLDOMDocument' class. **/
    m_XMLDomDocClass = m_JavaEnv->FindClass("com/fido/android/framework/service/XMLDOMDocument");
    if (m_XMLDomDocClass != NULL) {
        jmethodID constructor = m_JavaEnv->GetMethodID(m_XMLDomDocClass, "<init>", "()V");
        if (constructor != NULL) {
            m_XMLDomDocClassObject = m_JavaEnv->NewObject(m_XMLDomDocClass, constructor);
        }
        else DBG_ERROR(DBG_CTX, ("Can't create object of 'XMLDOMDocument' class!\n"));
    }
    else DBG_ERROR(DBG_CTX, ("Can't find 'XMLDOMDocument' class!\n"));

    /* Try to find 'XMLDOMNode' class. **/
    jclass localXMLDomNodeClass = m_JavaEnv->FindClass("com/fido/android/framework/service/XMLDOMNode");
    if (localXMLDomNodeClass != NULL) {
        jmethodID constructor = m_JavaEnv->GetMethodID(localXMLDomNodeClass, "<init>", "()V");
        if (constructor != NULL) {
            m_XMLDomNodeClassObject = m_JavaEnv->NewObject(localXMLDomNodeClass, constructor);
        }
        else DBG_ERROR(DBG_CTX, ("Can't create object of 'XMLDOMNode' class!\n"));
    }
    else DBG_ERROR(DBG_CTX, ("Can't find 'XMLDOMNode' class!\n"));

    }

} /* JNIXMLDOMDocument() **/
```

Comment: What mean second part is specific for Android ?

Comment: But you still should isolate your problems into smallest meaningful answerable pieces, not snowballing them together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First part: i don't know what type your `String` is. From the fact that it apparently can take `const char*` assignment and has a `c_str()` method, i guess a `std::string` or similar. Guessing further, your `String` is making a copy of the cstring you are giving to it, so it should survive releasing the original cstring. But you are releasing the cstring inside your `String`, not the one you got from `GetStringUTFChars`. So you are returning an invalid `String`.

So while the answer is yes, you indeed must call ReleaseStringUTFChars, the correct way is

```
String strXML;
const char* tempStr = m_JavaEnv->GetStringUTFChars(jstrXML, 0);
strXML = tempStr;
m_JavaEnv->ReleaseStringUTFChars(jstrXML,tempStr);
return strXML;
```

I can't answer the second part confidently, i am not into NDK. Make separate question.

Comment: Okay, I will try and let you know!

Comment: and if I call `m_XMLDomDocClass = m_JavaEnv->FindClass("com/fido/android/framework/service/XMLDOMDocument");` where m_XMLDomDocClass is jclass object and member of class, must I call `m_JavaEnv->DeleteGlobalRef(m_XMLDomDocClass );` or do something else ?

Comment: Please split your question and give chance to answer somebody else too. I am not confident in this part of JNI

Answer (score 0):

To answer your second question alone, there's not enough information provided, but in general you can attach and detach via a constructor/destructor pair if both are called by the same thread.

Comment: what information do you need ? I can provide you, I can give you classes .cpp and .h files if you want !

Comment: @ViToBrothers The missing information is whether or not the constructor and destructor are called by the same thread.

Comment: and if constructor and destructor are called from separated threads ?

Comment: @ViToBrothers Then it won't work, will it, because the current thread is different in each case. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: And what about this `m_XMLDomDocClassObject = m_JavaEnv->NewObject(m_XMLDomDocClass, constructor);` is this right or I need to write `newGlogalRef` ?

Comment: @ViToBrothers To get answers to your *brand new question* you should *ask* it as a brand new question, not just stick it in a comment to one answer that only you and I are reading.

Comment: Okay, I will do it and place here a link! ok ?

Comment: here is my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993038/right-way-to-work-with-jni-in-multithreading-application