# Right way to work with JNI in multithreading application

Tags: java, android, c++, c, multithreading

### Description

In my C++ application class `JNIXMLDocument` which made some JAVA method calls. In the constructor of `JNIXMLDocument` class I attach current thread and set it to my class member `JNIEnv* m_JavaEnv` and then use it in all methods. Also in the constructor I am trying to find my JAVA class `com/fido/android/framework/service/XMLDOMDocument` and set it to class member `m_XMLDocumentClass` and also get that class object from the class and set it to class member `m_XMLDocumentObject`.

### C++ Code

```
class JNIXMLDocument
{
    /* Constructor **/
    JNIXMLDocument()
    {
        /* Get JNI right version and set it. **/
        jint interface_id = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
        #ifdef JNI_VERSION_1_2
            interface_id = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
        #else
            interface_id = JNI_VERSION_1_1;
        #endif

        /* Trying to attach current thread. **/
        int res = g_JavaVirtualMachine->GetEnv(&m_JavaEnv, interface_id);
        if (res == JNI_EDETACHED || res == JNI_EVERSION) {
            res = g_JavaVirtualMachine->AttachCurrentThread(&m_JavaEnv, NULL);
        }

        /* Get Class from Java **/
        m_XMLDocumentClass = m_JavaEnv->FindClass("com/fido/android/framework/service/XMLDOMDocument");
        if (m_XMLDocumentClass != NULL) {
            /* Call java class constructor. **/
            jmethodID constructor = m_JavaEnv->GetMethodID(m_XMLDocumentClass , "<init>", "()V");
            m_XMLDocumentObject = m_JavaEnv->NewObject(m_XMLDocumentClass , constructor);    

        }

    }

    bool Initialize()
    {
        jmethodID method = m_JavaEnv->GetMethodID(m_XMLDocumentClass, "Initialize", "()Lorg/w3c/dom/Document;");
        jobject document = m_JavaEnv->CallObjectMethod(m_XMLDocumentObject , method);

    }

    private:
        JNIEnv* m_JavaEnv;
        jclass  m_XMLDocumentClass;
        jobject m_XMLDocumentObject;


};
```

### C++ Code (Right way)

```
class JNIXMLDocument
{
    /* Constructor **/
    JNIXMLDocument()
    {
        /* Get JNI right version and set it. **/
        jint interface_id = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
        #ifdef JNI_VERSION_1_2
            interface_id = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
        #else
            interface_id = JNI_VERSION_1_1;
        #endif

        JNIEnv* env;
        /* Trying to attach current thread. **/
        int res = g_JavaVirtualMachine->GetEnv(&env, interface_id);
        if (res == JNI_EDETACHED || res == JNI_EVERSION) {
            res = g_JavaVirtualMachine->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);
        }

        /* Get Class from Java **/
        jclass localClass = env->FindClass("com/fido/android/framework/service/XMLDOMDocument");
        if (localClass != NULL) {
            m_XMLDocumentClass = env->NewGlobalRef(localClass);
            /* Call java class constructor. **/
            jmethodID constructor = env->GetMethodID(localClass, "<init>", "()V");
            jobject localObject = env->NewObject(m_XMLDocumentClass , constructor);    
            m_XMLDocumentObject = env->NewGlobalRef(localObject );
        }

    }

    bool Initialize()
    {

    }

    private:
        jclass  m_XMLDocumentClass;
        jobject m_XMLDocumentObject;


};
```

### Questions

1. Is it right to set JNI interface pointer (`JNIEnv* m_JavaEnv`) in the constructor once and use it in the whole code ?
2. Is it right to set `jclass m_XMLDocumentClass` in the constructor and than use that variable in the all methods ?
3. Is it right to set `jobject m_XMLDocumentObject` in the constructor in this way `m_JavaEnv->NewObject(m_XMLDocumentClass , constructor);` or maybe I must call `NewGlobalRef`.
4. What problems can appear if my application work not in the same thread (use many threads) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it right to set JNI interface pointer (JNIEnv* m_JavaEnv) in the constructor once and use it in the whole code ?

No. It is thread-specific. That's what Attach/DetachCurrentThread are for. The only way this can work is if the C++ object is constructed and destroyed in the same thread.

> Is it right to set jclass m_XMLDocumentClass in the constructor and than use that variable in the all methods ?

No. It is a local reference, and it expires when the JNI method it was acquired in returns. You must save as a global or weak reference *unless* it is only going to be used within a single JNI method.

> ```
> Is it right to set jobject m_XMLDocumentObject in the constructor in this way m_JavaEnv->NewObject(m_XMLDocumentClass , constructor);
> ```

No: see above.

> or maybe I must call NewGlobalRef.

Yes, as above.

> What problems can appear if my application work not in the same thread (use many threads) ?

Mainly JVM crashes. The JVM assumes you follow all the rules in the JNI specification. So do that.

Comment: Thanks for answer +1. I have edited code can you tel me if it now more correct ?

Comment: @ViToBrothers No I can't, because, after several exchanges here and in your previous thread, you have still provided zero information about how this class is used. If you use it as per above and per the JNI Specification it will work. [StackOverflow doesn't know what you are thinking.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128551)